# Is there any way to sync Autodesk Forge viewer from one client to multiple

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

**Is there any way to sync Autodesk Forge viewer from one client to multiple**
We want to sync the Viewer oprations perfromed by one user to multiple users such that if User A chnages the camera postion other users can also see the chnage in there viewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking if the viewer has built-in sync capability, the answer is no. However implementing a sync functionality using socket.io is possible, on of my colleague used that technique for his [WEB VR site](http://www.vrok.it/). [Source code](https://github.com/KeanW/Vrok-It)